# How to successfully target the second part of a string in a span tag with specificity

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I understand the easiest way is to "class" something and then give the class the properties needed, however, 

1. I'm not a big fan of creating classes everywhere. That's what specificity and CSS mapping is for. 
2. It would take me forever to go through hundreds of pages to add these classes and some of the pages I'm not even supposed to even touch AT ALL!

So, at least I have a parent class to start with :) But my problem is, I have never had to target the second part of a text inside span tags divided by a `<br>` .

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="locations">
<ul>
    <li><strong>Address: </strong><span>47 Feed Mill Lane
        <br>
        Middlebury, VT 05753</span></li>
    <li><strong>Contact: </strong><span>John Doe</span></li>
    <li><strong>Phone: </strong><span>800-639-3191</span>/li>
    <li><strong>E-mail: </strong><span> <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS for the line in question. I added this specificity logic, but it is taking the entire content inside the `<span>` I want to select the portion after the `<br>` so I can indent it.

```
.locations > ul > li:first-child > span:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #34678a; /*for testing purposes only */
    text-indent:25px;
}
```

Here is the [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/dC4S4/1/)

And a little visual doesn't hurt ;)
[image]

Comment: OK, so what do you suggest I'd do

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using a [`<dl>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) for this?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I don't have a lot of control on some of the pages on the markup side. I have to do all my modifications through CSS and use the already defined classes to target children elements. A pain, I know, but they are paying for this so, lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS can't read the content of your elements and therefore has no idea where the `<br>` tag is. Target it instead with `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:text-top;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dC4S4/2/)**

You can use the following:

```
.locations > ul > li:first-child > span:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #34678a;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't target the second part of the text using css (as it's not a separate element). However you can still indent the text by using a combination of padding and negative margins.

Example 1:

```
.locations li {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 65px;
}
.locations li strong { 
    margin-left: -65px;
}
```

Example 2 (all strong tags same width):

```
.locations li { 
    display: block;
    padding-left: 70px;
}
.locations li strong {
    margin-left: -70px;
    width: 70px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but it's not my favorite all thanks to IE. They're picky with margins and all. And those pretty big margins too. But I liked it anyway. Thanks.